# the connect middleware for coffeescript?

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, node.js-connect

Yes I know `connect-assets`. But I hope the `coffeescript` files can be compiled on request. Just like in `stylus` middleware.

```
app.use(stylus.middleware(
  src: __dirname + "/assets",
  dest: __dirname + "/public"
))
```

So, is there anything that works this way?

I know `connect.compiler` too. But it has been removed in newest version of `connect`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just published a new module, [npm install connect-coffee-script](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-connect-coffee-script), which does just that. Documentation and a sample are provided as well as an [introduction article](http://www.adaltas.com/blog/2012/07/24/coffee-script-connect-middleware/).

Here's an exemple from the readme:

```
    var coffeescript = require('connect-coffee-script');
    var connect = require('connect');

    var app = connect();

    app.use(coffeescript({
        src: __dirname,
        dest: __dirname + '/public',
        bare: true
    }));

    app.use(connect.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: does this work with express? It doesnt seem to be working with the express static asset server for me

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.compiler({
  src: __dirname + "/assets",
  dest: __dirname + "/public",
  enable: ['coffeescript']
}));
```

could also add stylus to the enable array if you are using both!

im using express 2.5.9

Comment: I believe it's deprecated and will be removed in the future.